# Кавычки в названиях имений

Tags: кавычки

Названия имений, дворцов и вилл пишут в кавычках?
Как правильно?

Великокняжеский дворец «Дюльбер» (в пер. с араб. — прекрасный);
имение «Карасан»;  вилла «Мечта»; скала Монах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Названия вилл являются именами собственными и названиями, в то время как скала Монах - это географическое, даже скорее топографическое название, а такие слова пишутся без кавычек.